# Calculating Difference

Tags: tableau-api

I created a table.

I have used two calculated fields:

```
%Q12015 =IF ATTR([Qtr Data] )='Q12015' THEN SUM([AP Amount] )END/WINDOW_SUM(IF ATTR([Qtr Data]) ='Q12015' THEN SUM([AP Amount] )END )
Q42014=(IF ATTR([Qtr Data] )='Q42014' THEN SUM([AP Amount] )END)/WINDOW_SUM(IF ATTR([Qtr Data]) ='Q42014' THEN SUM([AP Amount] )END )
```

Now I wanted take difference between `%Q12015` and `%Q42014`.
I created one more calculated field `%Q12015-%Q42014` but I am getting `null` values.

Comment: Do you have null values for each field separately? You don't have an ELSE statement, so there might be

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have already solved this - but my response might serve someone else. I had the same problem. Then I changed my difference calculated variable to use the SUMs of the individual fields, and it worked. So, instead of

[Field 1]-[Field 2]

I did

SUM([Field 1])-SUM([Field 2])

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your two calculated fields both have ELSE 0.. Then you should be able to perform calcField1 - calcField2